# Schedule and monitor spring batch using IBM workload scheduler

Tags: spring, spring-batch, tivoli-work-scheduler

Is there any way to  schedule and monitor spring batch using IBM workload scheduler.

Comment: Is your application a java main or exposes REST APIs?
Are you running in containers or on a VM?

Comment: it exposes REST APIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application exposes REST APIs, the easiest solution is to use RESTful job type running on dynamic or zcentric agent, the job connects remotely to the REST API, so the agent can run on a separate machine or container.